# Why isn't the Airflow S3ListOperator listing files?

Tags: amazon-s3, airflow

I have the following code in an Airflow DAG:

```
    @task
    def list_outbound_file():
        context = get_current_context()
        step_params = context['ti'].xcom_pull(
            task_ids='set_run_params', key='return_value')

        s3_root_dir = step_params['%s3_root_dir']
        client_id = step_params['%client_id']
        client_dataset_version = step_params['%client_dataset_version']

        s3_file = S3ListOperator(
            task_id='list_outbound_file',
            bucket=bucket,
            prefix=f'{s3_root_dir}/outbound/client={client_id}/client_dataset_version={client_dataset_version}/',
            delimiter='/',
            aws_conn_id='aws_adaptive_retry_connection'
        )
        return s3_file.execute(context)
```

Here are the contents of the s3 location I'm trying list:
[image]

And this is the results of the task, in the Airflow log:

```
[2023-04-05, 13:52:20 UTC] {{s3.py:679}} INFO - Getting the list of files from bucket: paymentintegrity-chc-dev-dataplatform-us-east-1 in prefix: data/ecob/outbound/client=ecob_orxnv_wk-optumrx/client_dataset_version=2023-04-04-13-00-00-000000/ (Delimiter /)
[2023-04-05, 13:52:20 UTC] {{base.py:68}} INFO - Using connection ID 'aws_adaptive_retry_connection' for task execution.
[2023-04-05, 13:52:20 UTC] {{base_aws.py:100}} INFO - Retrieving region_name from Connection.extra_config['region_name']
[2023-04-05, 13:52:20 UTC] {{python.py:173}} INFO - Done. Returned value was: []
```

As you can see, the returned array is empty, even though there are objects at the location being searched.  Any idea what may be wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind!  I just noticed that the partition is not 'client=', but really 'client_id='.  Sigh...